# Reference for comparison theorem for ODE with Carathéodory vector fields

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations

I want references for classical comparison theorems but in the case where the vector field is less regular than the classical conditions of the Cauchy–Lipschitz theorem.

Let us consider a scalar ODE $$\frac{dx}{dt}=F(x,t)\tag{ODE}\label{ODE}$$ where $F$ is C1 in $x$ and measurable in $t$. We know that there is a unique solution which is a.e. differentiable (Hale, Jack K. [Ordinary differential equations](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Ordinary_Differential_Equations/LdTZJ4HwCv4C?gbpv=1&bsq=Theorem%205.3). 2d ed. Huntington, N.Y: R. E. Krieger Pub. Co, 1980, theorem 5.3).

I would like to find a referece for comparison theorem with the above conditions. Basically, if

$$x(t)\leq \gamma(0) + \int_0^tF(x(t),s)ds$$

and $\gamma$ is the solution for \eqref{ODE}, then for all $t\ge0$, we have $x(t)\leq\gamma(t)$.

[Levi - Ordinary Differential Equations, an intuitive introduction](https://anton-petrunin.github.io/417/lib/ODE.pdf) at page 80, theorem 3.3 claims it is true but gives no reference.

Can someone provide a reference for such result please?

Alternatively, can someone give a referece when $F$ is increasing in $x$ for each $t$?

Comment: MathJax note: if you soup up `\tag{ODE}` to `\tag{ODE}\label{ODE}` (or whatever label), then you can, just like in ordinary AMS-LaTeX, use `\eqref{ODE}` to get a nice hyperlinked reference.  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: Actually, based on those nice notes of Mark Levi you shared, it sounds like what you really a want is a reference that under mild conditions on the ODE (specifically an ODE of Carathéodory type) one has that the solution depends continuously on the initial condition, but this follows from uniqueness; see, e.g. Filippov, Aleksei Fedorovich. "Differential equations with discontinuous righthand sides: control systems". Therefore, a reference to Hale's book suffices.

Comment: I am not completely sure, the solution is differentiable a.e. so we have to adapt the proof from the notes I'd say